# Spring Boot and AngularJS deploy

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, deployment, web-deployment

I have a spring boot project and an AngularJS project generated with yeoman, both working when i start the servers on `localhost:8080` for spring boot and `localhost:9000` for angular.

Now I want to deploy both on the 8080 port.

I tryed to `gulp build -prod` and to copy the dist folder in `src/main/resources/static`, but when i `mvn clean install` and `mvn spring-boot:run` and I browse to `localhost:8080` I see the error page "Whitelabel Error Page". The api call are working, but I don't see the front end.

Any help?
I get no errors building and starting.

Comment: Look into your Server logfile for errors

Answer (score 0):

SolvedISH
the "gulp build -prod" created a file named "index-03d946d877.html" and spring doesn't recognize that. I just changed that name. How can I set the name of the file by default for a continuous integration?